# Youtube Ads Before Targeted Video

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to avoid Youtube Pre-Rolls while integrating Youtube Android SDK. Is there any way to avoid it?

I understand that there is a clause that:

> "does not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third
>   parties to: modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements
>   placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or
>   the YouTube player;"

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

However, after looking some application recommended from the below site and for example [5by](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiveby.jupiter&hl=en). I does not see them playing any Ads before any Youtube video.

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html

It would be great, if anyone have idea to bypass this Youtube Ad which comes before the targeted vide.

Finally, in any case (even if it is a piracy concern), I would like to understand, how applications like 5by would be able to by-pass ads that plays before the targeted video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete way to avoid Youtube Ads(Pre-Roll/Banners) is to implement a WebView based solution. Youtube has not integrated Ads in WebView probably applications like 5By is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Youtube Android API you can set the video mode to **Chromeless** during the init step (like in *onInitializationSuccess()*):

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean restored) {
    //...
    player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
    //...
}
```

**While in Chromeless mode the SDK doesn't load any ads in pre-roll** (before the video playback), instead it will show bottom overlay ads during the playback (which can be a little annoying anyway).

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the bottom overlay as well? Because similar application 5By does not show bottom overlay as well?